# Magento 1.8 - Product problem solved saving again

Tags: magento-1.8, search

I develop my own module to import products, and it works well, but there's some kind of problem with the search's extension, because, if you look for the products, that share part of the name, and we look for them in search input in the frontend, it shows less that the real count of them.

If ***i go to the product in the admin and saved it again, it been resolved***.

Why?it can be that `$product->save()`, works worst than Magento **save** button

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reindex the site, to check if it is relating to indexes? 
After Magento saves product, if indexes are 'update on save', it updates indexes to.

Comment: Yes, i indexed it and clear all the caches